# Form causes Run-time error -2147352571 (80020005)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form which is partially filled in automatically from tables. There is a combo, where the number of transaction is chosen and then there is a textbox, where I want to fill in the partner name (searched in sheets).

I have spend some long time to figure out what am I having wrong in my code. In the end I managed the code work, but it looks very mysterious for me and it's not clean.

The original code:

```
Private Sub ComboTransaction_Change()
    Dim ws_su As Worksheet
    Set ws_su = Worksheets("Sale Unsettled")
    TextPartner = ws_su.Range("SaleUnsettled_Start").Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(ComboTransaction), ws_su.Range("SaleUnsettled_Transactions"), 0), 1)
End Sub
```

The "solution":

```
Private Sub ComboTransaction_Change()
    Dim ws_su As Worksheet
    Set ws_su = Worksheets("Sale Unsettled")
    PartnerValue = ws_su.Range("SaleUnsettled_Start").Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(ComboTransaction), ws_su.Range("SaleUnsettled_Transactions"), 0), 1)
    TextPartner = PartnerValue
End Sub
```

Why I have to do it via the PartnerValue, that's a mystery for me. Not only it bothers me because it's messing up the code (there are more values which I have to fill in the same way), but I also have another forms (Purchase etc), where it works without this strange patch.

I would like to get rid of if so if you have any idea what's wrong, I will appreciate your message.

The only difference between TextPartner and PartnerValue is that TextPartner is a TextBox in the form and PartnerValue isn't.

Comment: The Run-time error means that it is a Type mismatch... did you try to use `TextPartner.Text = ws_su.Range.....` ?

Comment: Thanks Peter, this works. Although still I don't know why I don't need to have same .text in the other forms. Will use your suggestion, it's much better than my solution.

Comment: Thx. I've turned it into an answer. Because of the why... do you have any option statements in your code at the top of the module?

Comment: I don't exactly know what option statement means but if it's dim, I only have the one for worksheet stated in my question, nothing else.

Comment: You can declare `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to be sure you haven't misspelled variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Run-time error means that it is a Type mismatch.

Try to use

```
TextPartner.Text = ws_su.Range("SaleUnsettled_Start").Offset( _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(ComboTransaction), _
    ws_su.Range("SaleUnsettled_Transactions"), 0), 1)
```